# How to synchronize threads in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, concurrency, synchronization

I have ASP.NET application with code like this executing for web request:

```
ProcessAction(actionId)
```

I want to be sure that ProcessAction is not executed at the same time for the same actionId, so I need to do somehting like this:

```
WaitIfActionWithIdIsExecuting(actionId) 
ProcessAction(actionId)
```

What .NET synchronization mechanism should I use ? Mutex, Monitor, AutoResetEvent, ManualResetEvent ?

The situation when the thread will need to wait will be  very rare.

Comment: So looks like you have single thread which processes action one by one, that is correct?

Comment: Is this going to be inside 1 Request/Response?

Comment: The ProcessAction for the same actionId can be called from 2 or more ASP.NET requests.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a string from the id and intern the string, so that you are sure to always have the same string instance for an id, and lock using the string as identifier:

```
lock (String.Intern(actionId.ToString())) {
  ProcessAction(actionId);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use locks but in a web context I'd rather do synchronization through the database. Create a table for the actions with a column "status" that  signifies the state of the action (InProgress, Pending, Completed, etc.) Of course it depends on your particular task.

Comment: Yes, it could done by database (SQL Server) but it would require more changes, I just need a simple solution to avoid race conditions which happened in production system.